# CppCMS build constructor & declaration

Tags: c++, cppcms

From http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_forms,

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kw7hsf3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx),

> A declaration introduces one or more names into a program.....
>   Therefore, classes, structures, enumerated types, and other
>   user-defined types can be declared for each compilation unit

AFAIK, constructor should be in `myapp.cpp`, while declaration should be in `content.h`. So I put

There are 5 fields on the form. In CppCMS, the form built using 3 codes (the 4th codes are restriction for the fields)

1st codes:

```
name.message("Your Name");
sex.message("Sex");
marital.message("Marital Status");
age.message("Your Age");
submit.value("Send");
```

2nd codes:

```
add(name);
add(sex);
add(marital);
add(age);
add(submit);
```

3rd codes:

```
sex.add("Male","male");
sex.add("Female","female");
marital.add("Single","single");
marital.add("Married","married");
marital.add("Divorced","divorced");
```

4th codes, are restriction for the fields:

```
name.non_empty();
age.range(0,120);
```

I'm quite confused which one should be declaration

------------------added

I've tried add all above codes in `myapp.cpp` like below:

```
class myapp : public cppcms::application {
public:
    myapp(cppcms::service &srv) : cppcms::application(srv)
    {
        dispatcher().assign("",&myapp::info_form,this);
        mapper().assign("");
    }
    void info_form()
    {
        name.message("Your Name");
        sex.message("Sex");
        marital.message("Marital Status");
        age.message("Your Age");
        submit.value("Send");

        add(name);
        add(sex);
        add(marital);
        add(age);
        add(submit);

        sex.add("Male","male");
        sex.add("Female","female");
        marital.add("Single","single");
        marital.add("Married","married");
        marital.add("Divorced","divorced");

        name.non_empty();
        age.range(0,120);
    }
};
```

But it still giving error:

```
myapp.cpp: In member function ‘void myapp::info_form()’:
myapp.cpp:20:9: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
myapp.cpp:21:9: error: ‘sex’ was not declared in this scope
myapp.cpp:22:9: error: ‘marital’ was not declared in this scope
myapp.cpp:23:9: error: ‘age’ was not declared in this scope
myapp.cpp:24:9: error: ‘submit’ was not declared in this scope
myapp.cpp:24:9: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/cppcms/form.h:1574:20: note:   ‘cppcms::widgets::submit’
myapp.cpp: At global scope:
myapp.cpp:43:37: error: no ‘void myapp::main(std::string)’ member function declared in class ‘myapp’
my_skin.tmpl:4:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
my_skin.tmpl:8:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
my_skin.tmpl:12:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<<’ token
my_skin.tmpl:13:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

Comment: None of those are *declarations*.  Those are all functions being called.  The code that *declares* what `name`, `sex`, `marital` are... those are declarations.

Comment: I've tried put all above codes in `myapp.cpp`, but it says it need declaration

Comment: Have you declared a variable before?  If you haven't, this may be too complex a program for you to do now.  If you have, can you answer this regarding your first error - what is `name`?  Is it a `std::string`?  An `int`?

Comment: @Drew Dormann, `name` is `std::string`

Comment: I personally don't know what `name` is supposed to be, but I know that it's not a `std::string`.  I see `name.message` and `name.non_empty` in your code and `std::string` doesn't define those functions.  I can tell you this much: your first error is telling you that the compiler doesn't know what `name` is either.  There seem to be large missing portions of this code.